# 2-D Multi-Robots Avoiding Obstacles to Goal

Tags: java, a-star, robot

I am thinking of making and a three robots connecting together and forming a triangle (not in a physical way) and try to avoiding static obstacles on their way to the goal location in Java applet. Besides, I am focusing on A* algorithm for the path finding and choosing the center of system as reference point for the heuristic value. But I have found out that even the A* has generated a path based on the center of the system, the multi-robots might still bump into the obstacles while traveling to the goal. Is there any good way to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure your a* works fine?  what do you mean by connected robot? is it physical link? are they can be considered as single but large robot? are you sure you interpret your path correct?  can you provide some code?

Comment: Hmm, assuming that the obstacles aren't moving (if they are then it may be worth making that clear in the question) then, if your pathfinding is 'bumping' into obstacles then by definition it isn't working. Blocked nodes shouldn't be on the open list.

Comment: @user902383 Sorry for making this question unclear. All the implementation is simulating in Java applet and robots will be moving around and it can spread inward and outward but connecting as a triangle shape all the time. If I consider it as a single point, how can I count the heuristic value? or is there other good algorithm to solve coordinated moving robots other than A*?

Comment: @DFreeman Sorry for making this question unclear. I have already edited the question.

Comment: @Bruce just do additional check to find do you have any obstacle in radius of circle described by points where your robots are. i believe this should work. By addition it will be good if you provide us implementation of your a* algorithm

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an occupancy map for navigation make each tile at least the size of the robot network. Then if a cell is "not occupied" you know with certainty your entire network can fit in it without bumping any obstacles. The robots themselves could use a subdivided map. So you can imagine that one cell in the occupancy map represents a 3x3 cell to the bots. So the bots could still have precision in their formation using their subdivided cell while the path planning algorithm can ensure no matter how the bots are arranged they will be safe

I have included a toy example. The dark lines represent the cell for the occupancy map, this is what your path planning algorithm sees. The bots (the small yellow squares) subdivide the occupancy map internally (the planning algorithm doesn't need to know this goes on) and can also change their own configuration within a single occupancy cell.

The dark pink cells show where a physical block may be, but we consider the entire region (large cell) occupied. Even if the network could potentially navigate past the physical obstruction. By simply saying the region near it is occupied we reduce the odds of getting in tricky situations.

[image]

A* can only see the light pink and the light green cells. The robots can further subdivide the larger blocks internally